# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.2 returns "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found"

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I got this problem when I try to install new Worklight software (6.0.0.2) inside my Eclipse Luna.

[image]

How to fix these dependencies ?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM Worklight Studio 6.0.0.201409221914 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201409221914)
  Missing requirement: IBM Web Editor Common 1.2.0.v20130514_1852 (com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common 1.2.0.v20130514_1852) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [4.2.1,5.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Rich Page Editor Base 1.2.0.v20130516_0814 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v20130516_0814)
    To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.html [1.0.400.v20130504_0525]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Rich Page Editor - HTML 1.0.400.v20130504_0525 (com.ibm.etools.rpe.html 1.0.400.v20130504_0525)
    To: bundle com.ibm.etools.webtools.webedit.common [1.0.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM Worklight Studio 6.0.0.201409221914 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 6.0.0.201409221914)
    To: com.ibm.etools.rpe.feature.feature.group 1.0.200
```

Comment: Where a problem is solved by reinstalling software, the actual solution is lost to the mists of time. I suggest this question is put on hold as "typo/unrepro". From the official close reason: _It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer, install Worklight in fresh Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight 6.0x doesn't support eclipse Luna; you should install it on Juno, 4.2.2, Java Enterprise Edition. See list of supported software here:

http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=1343665214557

Specifically, Worklight runs on the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developer edition. Worklight is fairly specific on which version and which edition of eclipse is supported. For Worklight 6.0.0.x release, this version/edition of eclipse will work:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2

Comment: i installed it in Juno, but I occured the same error but with different dependency issue

Comment: Eclipse Indigo is not supported. If you want to install Worklight 6.0.0.x, use Eclipse Juno Java EE

Comment: Did you check that you had the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developer edition? Worklight is fairly specific on which version and which edition of eclipse is supported:  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2

Comment: Also, I see that you are installing the v6.0x fix with a datestamp of 20140922. Can you state the name of the zip file you are installing? Are you upgrading an existing installation? Did you get this fix from IBM's FixCentral? Or did you download from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure. Check your internet connection or your proxy configurations.
This errors are also caused in absence of connection.

Proxy setting:
http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/